# Remove one blank cell before every filled cell in a string array

Tags: java, android, string, split, substring

I am using this code :

```
ArrayList<String> getques = db.getSolutionData(levelno, level);
    String str = getques.get(0);            
    stringarr = str.split("");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stringarr));
```

This is the result output:

`07-23 16:10:37.031: I/System.out(2548): [, C,  ,  , D,  ,  , F,  , I,  ,  ,  , A,  , F,  , A,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , B,  , C,  , D,  ,  , H,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , C,  , I,  , G,  ,  , A,  ,  , E,  ,  , B,  , I,  ,  ,  ,  , F,  , G,  ,  , H,  ,  , A,  ,  , E,  , D,  , I,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , F,  ,  , I,  , G,  , E,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , D,  , B,  , A,  ,  ,  , H,  , B,  ,  , G,  ,  , F]`

Now I want to remove one blank cell before every cell that is filled.
for eg : before the second cell there is a blank cell which I want to remove, before `,D,` there are 2 blank cells so I would like to remove one from those, before `I` one blank cell, before `A`, 3 blank cells so I would like to remove one of them, etc.
Thus I came to the conclusion that I would like to remove one blank cell before every filled cell.

I have used :

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String s : stringarr)
        if (!s.equals(""))
            list.add(s);
    stringarr = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

But it removes all the blank cells. Kindly help, Thankx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// original array
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(stringarr);
        // modified array
        List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
//      insertion index
        int index = 0;
        for(int i =0 ; i< list.size() ;i++){
            if(!list.get(i).equals(" ") && !list.get(i).equals("")){
                index++;
                //remove extra empty space from end of modified array
                if(l.size() > 1){
                    l.remove(i - index);
                }
            }
            //make sure that first index not empty
            if(i - index == -1 ) {
                index--;
            }
            l.add(i - index, list.get(i));


        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(list));
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(l));
```

result will be somthing like this :

```
[[ C,  ,  ,  D,  ,  ,  F,  ,  I,  ,  ,  ,  A,  ,  F,  ,  A,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  B,  ,  C,  ,  D,  ,  ,  H,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  C,  ,  I,  ,  G,  ,  ,  A,  ,  ,  E,  ,  ,  B,  ,  I,  ,  ,  ,  ,  F,  ,  G,  ,  ,  H,  ,  ,  A,  ,  ,  E,  ,  D,  ,  I,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  F,  ,  ,  I,  ,  G,  ,  E,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  D,  ,  B,  ,  A,  ,  ,  ,  H,  ,  B,  ,  ,  G,  ,  ,  F]]
[[ C,  ,  D,  ,  F,  I,  ,  ,  A,  F,  A,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  B,  C,  D,  ,  H,  ,  ,  ,  ,  C,  I,  G,  ,  A,  ,  E,  ,  B,  I,  ,  ,  ,  F,  G,  ,  H,  ,  A,  ,  E,  D,  I,  ,  ,  ,  ,  F,  ,  I,  G,  E,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  D,  B,  A,  ,  ,  H,  B,  ,  G,  ,  F]]
```

Make sure that it's blank or space cell :

```
if(!list.get(i).equals(" ") && !list.get(i).equals("")){
```

I think this will work fine.

Comment: this is too complicated and imho wont work if we have two letters without spaces.

Answer (score 1):

```
  List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
   for (String i:str){
       if(!i.equals("")){
           list.add("");
           list.add(i);
       }
   }    

stringarr = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

try if it works..

Comment: [, C, ,  , ,  , , D, ,  , ,  , , F, ,  , ,I, ,  , ,  , ,  , ,A, ,  , ,F, ,  , ,A, ,  , ,  , ,  , ,  , ,  , ,  , ,  , ,  , ,  , ,  , , B, ,  , , C, ,  , , D, ,  , ,  , , H, ,  , ,  , ,  , ,  , ,  , , C, ,  , , I, ,  , , G, ,  , ,  , , A, ,  , ,  , , E, ,  , ,  , , B, ,  , , I, ,  , ,  , ,  , ,  , , F, ,  , , G, ,  , ,  , , H, ,  , ,  , , A, ,  , ,  , , E, ,  , , D, ,  , , I, ,  , ,  , ,  , ,  , ,  , , F, ,  , ,  , , I, ,  , , G, ,  , , E, ,  , ,  , ,  , ,  , ,  , ,  , ,  , ,  , ,  , ,  , , D, ,  , , B, ,  , , A, ,  , ,  , ,  , , H, ,  , , B, ,  , ,  , , G, ,  , ,  , , F]

Comment: are you getting the same output?

Comment: actually it is increasing the blank cells rather than cutting them down...above comment is the output

Comment: ok.. i will check again and gives you the solution if i get it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try some thing like this

```
 String[] str=new String[]{"","C","","","","D"};
   List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
   for (String i:str){
       if(!i.equals("")){
           list.add("");
           list.add(i);
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
boolean emptyCellRemoved = false;
for (String s : stringarr) {
    if ("".equals(s)) {
        if (emptyCellRemoved == false) {
            emptyCellRemoved = true;
        } else {
            list.add(s);
        }
    } else {
        emptyCellRemoved = false;
        list.add(s);
    }
}
stringarr = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```

Comment: this will not remove first blank cell

Comment: it will. emptyCellRemoved is false, so fist empty cell will be dropped.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :)

```
boolean oneRemoved = false;
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String s : stringarr){

        if (s.equals("") && !oneRemoved){               
            oneRemoved = true;
        } else {
            list.add(s);
            if (!s.equals("")){
               oneRemoved = false;
            } 
        }

    }
    stringarr = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
```